# table of contents design

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to make a proceedding book.

On the front matter, I want four chapters to be appears in the table of contents. The copyright, the Organizing Committee, the Reviewers, and the table of contents

[image: the chapter name like this one]

[image: the chapter name like this one]

[image: there is no chapter name in the copyright]

[image: I want the table of content like this one]

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, you only need to run the book class and use the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`-commands.  Frontmatter will enable small roman page numbers.  It also suppresses the caption numbers.

This is my suggestion

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Copyright}
\label{cha:copyright}

(C) 2016

\chapter{Organizing committee}
\label{cha:organizing-committee}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Patron & Prof. Dr. Ramlan\\
  Chairman & Prof. Dr. Majid\\
\end{tabular}

\chapter{Reviewers}
\label{cha:reviewers}

We thank all reviewers.

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{cha:introduction}

\end{document}
```

Here is a crop of the output:
[image]

One little thing is still missing: the entry for the table of columns in itself.  I don't see any helpful information in inserting the table of contents into the table of contents.  No one will search the chapter "Table Of Contents" by looking into the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

The details depend on the document class that you use as well as on the structuring commands. The basic idea is to add the command

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{level}{title}
```

after each headline, where `level` is either `chapter` or `section` depending on whether you want to have the contents entry to appear like a chapter or a section entry. `title` is the text to be added to the table of contents.

For the `\tableofcontents` a trick is needed to make sure that the page number is correct, since you cannot add the command directly after the headline. Use

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{level}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents
```

(or use `\clearpage` if the table of contents does not start on an odd page).

Here is an example using the `book` class. The detailed formatting depends on the particular class and packages that you use.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter*{Copyright}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Copyright}
\blindtext

\chapter*{Organizing Committee}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Organizing Committee}
\blindtext

\chapter*{Reviewers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Reviewers}
\blindtext

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\end{document}
```

> [image]